# Custom gesture not sending action message

Tags: objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have created a `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass called `LongPressGestureRecognizer` to simulate a long press gesture. (Yes, I know about the concrete subclass which already exists, I'm just learning objective-c and experimenting a bit.)

I have overridden only the following methods :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible;
    [self performSelector:@selector(setState:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized] afterDelay:2];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    self.state   = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}
```

and in my view controller with a property `recognizer` to store the gesture recogniser, i have the following code:

```
- (LongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (!_recognizer) {
        _recognizer = [[LongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    }
    return _recognizer;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.recognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(log:)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.recognizer];
}

- (IBAction)log:(LongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    //blah blah blah
}
```

My problem is that `log:` is not getting called at all... By logging the `UIGestureRecogniserState`s in the console, I know that the gesture recogniser is working as expected as far as states are concerned...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other issues as well, but I can tell you that your `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` call isn't going to work the way you're hoping; you'll end up passing a pointer to an `NSNumber` object instead of an `int`, so `state` will be set to some kind of junk value. Create a method that will do `self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized` and call that instead.